# Can't find iTunes U files to delete

Tags: itunes-u

I have an 80 GB iPod Classic.  It has many iTunes U episodes on it that I want to delete.  But when it is plugged into my Mac I can't find these episodes listed anywhere.  I've looked in the iTunes U, Podcasts and general Music lists.  Anyone know how I can get the titles to show up so I can delete them?  (Using iTunes vers. 11.3, but this has been going on for almost a year)

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of iTunes seem to hang on to the list of podcasts etc, though they're not actually on the machine. Try setting up an iTunes Smart Playlist for 'Local Only' to see which are actually still on the machine.

[image: iTunes Smart Playlist]